# "Я знаю точно: невозможное - возможно" Правильно ли поставлены знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

В частности, сомневаюсь по поводу тире. Может быть, оно вовсе не нужно здесь?

Answer (score 3):

Я знаю точно: **невозможное возможн**о, 
Сойти с ума, влюбиться так неосторожно,
Найти тебя, не отпускать ни днём ни ночью,
**Всё невозможное — возможно**, знаю точно.

Вот текст (добавлено несколько запятых). Тире стоит  только в конечной фразе, оно явно **авторское**, обозначает паузу (перед окончательным выводом),  при этом логически подчеркнуто подлежащее.

По правилам тире не ставится, если сказуемое выражено прилагательным, наречием, местоимением.

Розенталь [§ 5. Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92#pp9210)

**Тире не ставится**: 10. Если сказуемое выражено прилагательным (в том числе местоименным) или предложно-именным сочетанием, тире перед сказуемым обычно не ставится: Погода несносная, дорога скверная, ямщик упрямый… (П.); Земля велика и прекрасна (Ч.); Вишнёвый сад мой! (Ч.); Небо без единого облачка; Люди здесь необыкновенной доброты.

**Тире перед сказуемым-прилагательным ставится:**
1) при логическом или интонационном членении предложения:Зрачки — кошачьи, длинные (Ш.); Высота возле разбросанных домиков хутора — командная (Каз.);