# Знаки препинания в припеве песни "Невозможное возможно"

Tags: пунктуация

Постановка знаков препинания отличается от сайта к сайту.
Возможно, вам известен авторитетный источник. Если нет, предлагаю обсудить правильность таких вариантов, встречающихся в интернете:

*Я знаю точно (- или :)

Невозможное возможно (, или .)

Сойти с ума,

Влюбиться так неосторожно (, или .)

Найти тебя,

Не отпускать ни днём ни ночью,

Всё невозможное возможно -

Знаю точно.*

Я бы расставил так:

*Я знаю точно:

Невозможное возможно.

Сойти с ума,

Влюбиться так неосторожно,

Найти тебя,

Не отпускать ни днём ни ночью...

Всё невозможное возможно -

Знаю точно.*

Comment: См. также https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/433905/%d0%af-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8e-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, что в песенных текстах вид знака препинания не так важен, как в обычной прозе: обозначили паузу – и хорошо. Но если ставить знаки по обычным правилам, то я бы выбрала такой вариант:

**Я знаю точно,
Невозможное возможно: 
Сойти с ума,
Влюбиться так неосторожно, 
Найти тебя,
Не отпускать ни днём ни ночью...
Всё невозможное – возможно, 
Знаю точно.**

Пояснение:

1) Я знаю точно/знаю точно - считаем вводными предложениями.

2) После двоеточия следует раскрытие темы (что именно возможно). Два двоеточия ставить нельзя (некрасиво и не приветствуется).